# Is there a javascript command for 'only run when the mouse is over but stop when its not over'

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know about onmouseover but I have a circle on a page that lights up when the mouse hovers over it. But it stays lit when the mouse comes off it until it hovers again, when it turns off again. Its really irritating. Is there a one instruction to trigger only when hovering? Here's the code, mostly not relevant though

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.group * 3; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag)
      .on('mouseover', connectedNodes)
      .on("click",  function(d) { getprofile(d); });
```

Comment: isn't there also an onmouseout event? Maybe have a listener for onmouseout that turns it off in addition to your onmouseover that turns it on?

Comment: There is an event `onmouseout`.  Maybe that is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define on mouse out event.
So your code will be like this:

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(graph.nodes)
          .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("r", function(d) { return d.group * 3; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
          .call(force.drag)
          .on('mouseover', connectedNodes)
          .on('mouseout', doSomethingCallback)
          .on("click",  function(d) { getprofile(d); });

function doSomethingCallback(){
  fill your circle with the original color
}
```

Comment: Lovely. Thanks. That sorted it

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `mouseleave`. Here's a D3 demo of it: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5247027

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.on('mouseout', function(){});` to stop the function started whit mouseover.